# Errors in RFE and KFOLD method using Logistic Regression

Tags: python-3.x

I am getting errors in RFE and K-Fold method in python using logistic regression. How to achieve error-free code?

```
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
from sklearn.feature_selection import RFE
accuracies = []
feature_set = []
max_accuracy_so_far = 0
for i in range(1,len(X[0])+1):
    selector = RFE(LogisticRegression(), i,verbose=1)
    selector = selector.fit(X, y)
    current_accuracy = selector.score(X,y)
    accuracies.append(current_accuracy)
    feature_set.append(selector.support_)
    if max_accuracy_so_far < current_accuracy:
        max_accuracy_so_far = current_accuracy
        selected_features = selector.support_
    print('End of iteration no. {}'.format(i))
X_sub = X[:,selected_features]
```

```
#KFOLD model score
scores = []
max_score = 0
from sklearn.model_selection import KFold
kf = KFold(n_splits=4,random_state=0,shuffle=True)
for train_index, test_index in kf.split(X_sub):
    X_train, X_test = X_sub[train_index], X_sub[test_index]
    y_train, y_test = y[train_index], y[test_index]
    current_model = LogisticRegression()
    #train the model
    current_model.fit(X_train,y_train)
    #see performance score
    current_score = model.score(X_test,y_test)
    scores.append(current_score)
    if max_score < current_score:
        max_score = current_score
        best_model = current_model
best_model.intercept_ 
best_model.coef_
```

```
What is the correct output?
```

I expect the output to be correct